# eas build -p android fails

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

When I run `eas build -p android` I get an error `Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.`

I couldn't do the regular `expo build:android` and got some strange error when I tried to name my Android package. So instead I followed this that came up after I tried the expo build.

```
expo build:android has been superseded by eas build. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60

Run the following:

› npm install -g eas-cli
› eas build -p android https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

expo build:android will be discontinued on January 4, 2023 (357 days left).
```

So if I go into the logs on expo.dev I see this:

```
> Task :react-native-svg:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.
[stderr] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
[stderr]    > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
[stderr]      Required by:
[stderr]          project :app
[stderr]          project :app > project :expo
[stderr]          project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
[stderr]          project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
[stderr]          project :app > project :react-native-screens
[stderr]          project :app > project :react-native-svg
[stderr]          project :app > project :expo > project :expo-modules-core
[stderr]          project :app > project :expo > project :expo-splash-screen
[stderr]          project :app > project :expo > project :expo-updates
[stderr]       > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
[stderr]          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
[stderr]             > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
[stderr]                > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 3m 21s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

I cant post the whole log because stackoverflow won't let me publish my question because it "looks like spam" so I just copied the error part of the log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCenter is currently down, and it is required on for a number of dependencies from React Native - in particular:

```
com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1
com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3
com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.54.0
com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.54.0
com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.54.0
```

https://status.expo.dev/

Comment: this seems unrelated. please read your full logs and refer to https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/ for more info on how to understand the true cause of the build failure

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I later resolved my issue. Forgot to delete this. Deleting now. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a global JCenter outage (which happens from time to time).

You can monitor status [here](https://%20https://status.gradle.com)